EQ function is not returning correct values
I have a weird problem. If I use a hardcoded value it works and if I use the same value in a string var if returns null from the DB
Example:

works ok

let query = supabase
.from('Posts')
.select("*")
.eq('titleLink', "Third")
const { data } = await query.single();
console.log("data " + data)

2 return null
async function getPosts(titleLinkOfPost: string) {
//...
console.log("titleLinkOfPost: " + titleLinkOfPost)
//...
let query = supabase
.from('Posts')
.select("*")
.eq('titleLink', titleLinkOfPost)
const { data } = await query.single();

console.log("data " + data)

for this line console.log("titleLinkOfPost: " + titleLinkOfPost) the output is
titleLinkOfPost: "Third"

Have you tried to merge the .single() to the upper query? let {data} = await supabase.from().select().eq().single();

const { data }  = await supabase
.from('Posts')
.select("*")
.eq('titleLink', titleLinkOfPost)
.single();
@phuc16102001 didn't work : <
